# create a summary of object sizes in one comma separated list

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a large file containing two fields the first one representing an object name  and the second field represents the size of that object:

```
A 1
A 2
B 4
ABC 12
C 5
A 9
B 3
ABC 6
```

I would like to summarize the list with the following format:

```
A 1,2,9
ABC 12,6
B 4,3
C 5
```

the solution I came up with is to create a unique list of the objects present in the file, iterate through it and match it with the original file

```
for object in $(awk '{print $1}' objects_with_sizes.txt | sort -u);do
    echo -n "$object "
    awk -v pattern="$object" '$1==pattern{printf "%s%s" ,sep,$2;sep=","} END{print ""}' objects_with_sizes.txt  
done
```

This implementation takes a long time to run, is there a more efficient way of creating the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ object[$1]= (object[$1]==""?"":object[$1] ",") $2 }
  END  { for(obj in object) print obj, object[obj] }' infile
A 1,2,9
B 4,3
C 5
ABC 12,6
```

A bit more efficient (use of the memory; matter for a huge file that cannot fit into the memory), i.e not buffering the file partially into the memory that awk command alone does above but only until a object key changes:

```
$ <infile sort -k1,1 -k2,2n |\
  awk 'pre!=$1 { if(obj) { print obj; obj="" } }
               { obj= (obj==""?$1 " ":obj ",") $2; pre=$1 }
  END{ if(obj) print obj }'
A 1,2,9
ABC 6,12
B 3,4
C 5
```

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -t ' ' -s -g 1 collapse 2 <file
A 1,2,9
ABC 12,6
B 4,3
C 5
```

Options:

- `-t '_'` use the space character as field delimiter
- `-s` sort the input before grouping
- `-g 1` group on the first field
- `collapse 2` collapse values of the second field into comma-separated list

Answer (score 1):

We can sort then feed to GNU sed which compares the current first field with previous to generate the comma separated OR print till that point.

```
$ < file sort -s -k1,1 \
| sed -Ee '
  :a
    $!N
    s/^((\S+)\s.*)\n\2\s+(\S+)/\1,\3/
  ta
  P;D
' -
A 1,2,9
ABC 12,6
B 4,3
C 5
```